# The style is not applied when I change the selector in the CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have files: index.php / register.php / style.css

In index.php I have div with id="square" and I use it in style.css

```
#square{
width: 300px;
height: 170px;
background-color: green;
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: 130px;}
```

In register.php if I use the same div with id="square" I have the same effects and my CSS file is working.

But if I change id for exmaple to "square1" my CSS file is not working for register.php

```
#square1{
width: 500px;
background-color: green;}
```

Could you help me guys???

Comment: of course, the selector defined in your css should match with the same identifier in the markup - show your actual markup

Comment: Okey, but I want to that my index.php display what is in #square, but register.php what is in #square1

Comment: what is the id actually used in the markup of register.php? Does that page load the style.css?

Comment: Can you share both index.php and register.php useful parts?

Comment: did you do a hard refresh to force the browser to reload your stylesheet?

Comment: Pete, yes I did it. I uploaded my code below.

Comment: Then you need to create a [mcve] as the code you have provided should work

Answer (score 2):

You should use classes, like this:

`<div class="square" id="square1">
<div class="square" id="square2">
<div class="square" id="square3">`

Then if you use .square { } in css, all squares get the same properties.
Now you can also edit each square seperately by using id #square1 { }

Comment: When I created new file only with divs like a squares it is working for me. For sure I have sth wrong with my code. Thank you very much for help!!!